# Create lists excluded duplicates in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, list, excel-formula, duplicates

I have a MS Excel list with only 5 values in column A. There will always be one random duplicated value within this list. For example:

A1:A5
Heart
Finger
Hair
Heart
Nose

Here Heart is listed twice. I need a formula that detects the value that occurs twice in the list, and type this formula into colum B1:B3 to create a new list. The outcome of the new list should be the remaining three values - hence should not include Heart since it occurs twice.

Another example with preferred outcome...

A1:A5 Heart, Nose, Hair, Finger, Finger

B1:B3 Heart, Nose, Hair

In this example Finger is listed twice (in colum A) and therefore  excluded in colum B (the new list).

Would really appreciate all hjelp and adwice with respect to how this could be solved with a formula in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with helper columns, which you should be, you can use this solution:

Helper column 1 (enter in cell `B1` and drag down):

```
= COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
```

Helper column 2 (enter in cell `C1` and drag down):

```
= IF(B1=1,RANK(B1,B:B,1)+COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)-1,0)
```

Output column (enter in cell `D1` and drag down):

```
= INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),C:C,0))
```

See below working example:

[image]

If necessary, you can use `IFERROR` to handle the errors in the `D` column.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helper colums is perfectly fine. Will try out your solution at work tomorrow. 

Really appreciate your help, thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Couple options:

1. If you don't care about position of the outputted elements, then this formula works:

   ```
   =IF(COUNTIF($A1:$A$5,A1)>1,"",A1)
   ```
2. A VBA approach:

   ```
   Public Function GetUniqueEntries(InputRange As Range) As Variant
       Dim Cell As Range
       Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

       For Each Cell In InputRange
           If Not dict.exists(Cell.Value2) Then dict.Add Cell.Value2, Cell.Value2
       Next

       GetUniqueEntries = Application.Transpose(dict.Items())
   End Function
   ```

   Enter this as `=GetUniqueEntries(A1:A5)`. This is an array based formula, so remember to select a wide enough output selection and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try your solution at work tomorrow  Really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Two formulas:

You can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,$A$1:$A$5)=1)*ROW($A$1:$A$5),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

If you have Excel 2016 with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$A$1:$A$5) & "</s></t>","//s[not(.=preceding::*) and not(.=following::*)]"),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

and fill down.

[image]

- create an `XML` where each row is a separate node.
- use `FILTERXML` with an `xPath` that filters out any node that is followed by or preceded by it's identical twin.

**EDIT:**  If your version of Excel is prior to 2010, and lacks the `AGGREGATE` function, you can use the following **array** formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,SMALL(IFERROR(1/(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,$A$1:$A$5)=1)*ROW($A$1:$A$5),10^6),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I have tried your first formula - pasted it in colum B1, but it returns the errormessage #Name?

Comment: @SveinAustheim What version of Excel?

Comment: @SveinAustheim See my edit for a version that will work with versions of Excel prior to 2010

Comment: I use Office 365 ProPlus

Comment: The edited version work! Thanks a lot! Much appreciated :)